# concatinate all rows of a column into single value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table called Rule.

```
RuleId    Name
1          A1
2          A2
3          A3
.
.
.
```

Now I want all the names as single result.

may be like `@allnames = A1,A2,A3`

Can somebody advise how to write query for this without using loops?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT @allnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + Name
                      FROM table1
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c24c3/5)

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @names NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @names = coalesce(@names + ',', '') + coalesce(Name, '') 
FROM (SELECT distinct Name FROM Rule) x

print @names
```

Comment: This appends duplicates. anyway to get distinct ?

Comment: @mmssaann sure, although it is not specified in the question

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE ([RuleId] INT, Name CHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @temp([RuleId], Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'A1'),
    (2, 'A2'),
    (3, 'A3')

DECLARE @all_names NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @all_names = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Name
    FROM @temp
    --ORDER BY Name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @all_names
```

Output -

```
---------------
A1,A2,A3
```